# Running a Spark job with spark-submit across the whole cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, emr, amazon-emr

I have recently set up a Spark cluster on Amazon EMR with 1 master and 2 slaves.

I can run `pyspark`, and submit jobs with `spark-submit`.

However, when I create a standalone job, like `job.py`, I create a SparkContext, like so:

```
sc=SparkContext("local", "App Name")
```

This doesn't seem right, but I'm not sure what to put there.

When I submit the job, I am sure it is not utilizing the whole cluster.

If I want to run a job against my entire cluster, say 4 processes per slave, what do I have to

a.) pass as arguments to `spark-submit`

b.) pass as arguments to `SparkContext()` in the script itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create spark context using

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

and you have to submit the program to `spark-submit` using the following command for spark standalone cluster

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://<sparkMasterIP>:7077 code.py
```

For Mesos cluster

```
./bin/spark-submit --master mesos://207.184.161.138:7077 code.py
```

For YARN cluster

```
./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster code.py
```

For YARN master, the configuration would be read from HADOOP_CONF_DIR.